# Javascript Being Converted to Chinese Characters

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this simple angular app using angular 1.6.1.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">

<head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <home></home>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('App', []);

    app.component('home', {
            template: '<h1>{{$ctrl.head}}</h1><ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul>',
            controller: function() {
                var vm = this;

                this.head = "ONE";
            }
        });
})();
```

This will load OK and display corretly in IE11, but fails to load on Chrome( 55.0.2883.87 beta (64-bit) or FF (51.0b13 (32-bit) and I have absolutly no idea why ....

whne I click on the app.js in Sources tab in Chrom Dev Tool the source is in wierd chineese like characters, but looking at source via Notepad++, all looks OK ... ?!?!

here is a screenshot of devconsole on chrome

[image]

I can see the same issue for every JS file I add to index.html.
I didn't change any locale settings aor anything else in the browsers ot my PC ...

I have no idea why is this happening. Anyone seen anything like this?

Comment: I will try on other PC later, I'm not really sure what is going on ...

Comment: Wow, I would rename this question to "Javascript Being Converted to Chinese Characters"

Comment: You may be saving the `app.js` file in a different locale/encoding. Make sure you are saving the file in UTF.

Comment: yes you are right, see my answer below ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all files were created in command line by typing

```
echo "" >> app.js
```

and this has set encoding to `UCS-2 LE BOM` as displayed in Notepad++, and for some unknow reason Chrome and firefox could not read the files correctly ...

[image]

So converting file to `UTF-8-BOM` in Notepad++ (Menu -> Encoding -> Convert to UTF-8-BOM) file was read fine and all worked...

I would be still interested on why old IE managed to read the site OK, but more modern browsers failed ...

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. In my case, the main HTML page was in localhost and it was calling external .js files out of my control. The problem was present in modern versions of Chrome and Firefox (but not in Internet Explorer). I discovered that the HTML page had been accidentally created in Unicode, instead of UTF8 or ANSI. I used notepad.exe to save it as ANSI (since it was only in English) and that solved the problem.

Comment: You should rather save all files you use on the web in UTF-8. It's kind a standard nowdays.